# GetNode<Timer>("/root/Main/StartTimer") giving System.InvalidCastException

Tags: godot

I'm doing the "Your First 2D Game" in Godot because I'm a beginner. I used C# as my script language.

I'm having a problem with GetNode("/root/Main/StartTimer") giving to me a  System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

But, StartTimer is the Timer type. So, There's no way it could launch this exception.

I'm exactly at this page of the tutorial:
https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/first_2d_game/05.the_main_game_scene.html

```
public void New_Game()
{
    Score = 0;

    var player = GetNode<Player>("/root/Main/Player");
    var startPosition = GetNode<Position2D>("/root/Main/StartPosition");
    player.Start(startPosition.Position);

    GetNode<Timer>("/root/Main/StartTimer").Start();
}
```

Well, I don't know what to do, since I'm following the tutorial. I think it shouldn't happen because StartTimer is the type Timer, screenshot below:
[image: my screen showing that the StartTimer is type Timer]

These are all my scripts:

Main.cs script:

```
using Godot;
using System;

public class Main : Node
{
// Declare member variables here. Examples:
// private int a = 2;
// private string b = "text";

#pragma warning disable 649
[Export]
public PackedScene MobScene;
#pragma warning restore 649

public int Score;

// Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
public override void _Ready()
{ 
    GD.Randomize();
    New_Game();
}

//  // Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous frame.
//  public override void _Process(float delta)
//  {
//      
//  }

public void Game_Over()
{
    GetNode<Timer>("MobTimer").Stop();
    GetNode<Timer>("ScoreTimer").Stop();
}

public void New_Game()
{
    Score = 0;

    var player = GetNode<Player>("/root/Main/Player");
    var startPosition = GetNode<Position2D>("/root/Main/StartPosition");
    player.Start(startPosition.Position);

    GetNode<Timer>("/root/Main/StartTimer").Start();
    //Timer StartTimer = GetNode<Timer>("/root/Main/StartTimer");
}

public void OnScoreTimerTimeout()
{
    Score++;
}

public void OnStartTimerTimeout()
{
    GetNode<Timer>("MobTimer").Start();
    GetNode<Timer>("ScoreTimer").Start();
}

public void OnMobTimerTimeout()
{
    //Create a new instance of the Mob Scene
    var mob = (Mob)MobScene.Instance();

    //Choose a random Location on Path2D
    var mobSpawnLocation = GetNode<PathFollow2D>("MobPath/MobSpawnLocation");
    mobSpawnLocation.Offset = GD.Randi();

    //Set the mon's direction perpendicular to the path direction.
    float direction = mobSpawnLocation.Rotation + Mathf.Pi / 2;

    //Set the mob's position to a random location.
    mob.Position = mobSpawnLocation.Position;

    //Add some randomness to the direction
    direction += (float)GD.RandRange(-Mathf.Pi / 4, Mathf.Pi / 4);
    mob.Rotation = direction;

    // Choose the velocity.
    var velocity = new Vector2((float)GD.RandRange(150.0, 250.0), 0);
    mob.LinearVelocity = velocity.Rotated(direction);

    // Spawn the mob by adding it to the Main scene.
    AddChild(mob);

}
}
```

Mobs.cs script:

```
using Godot;
using System;

public class Mob : RigidBody2D
{
// Declare member variables here. Examples:
// private int a = 2;
// private string b = "text";

// Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
public override void _Ready()
{
    var animSprite = GetNode<AnimatedSprite>("AnimatedSprite");
    animSprite.Playing = true;
    string[] mobTypes = animSprite.Frames.GetAnimationNames();
    animSprite.Animation = mobTypes[GD.Randi() % mobTypes.Length];
}

// // Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous 
frame.
// public override void _Process(float delta)
// {
//     
//  }

public void OnVisibilityNotifier2DScreenExited()
{
    QueueFree();
}   
}
```

Player.cs script:

```
using Godot;
using System;

public class Player : Area2D
{
// Declare member variables here. Examples:
// private int a = 2;
// private string b = "text";

//How fast the player will move (pixel/sec).
[Export]
public int Speed = 400;
[Signal]
public delegate void Hit();
// Size of the game window.
public Vector2 ScreenSize;

// Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
public override void _Ready()
{
    ScreenSize = GetViewportRect().Size;
    Hide(); //Player is hidden when the game starts
}

// Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous 
frame.
public override void _Process(float delta)
{
    var velocity = Vector2.Zero; //Tha Player's movement vector

    if (Input.IsActionPressed("move_right"))
    {
        velocity.x += 1;
    }
    if (Input.IsActionPressed("move_left"))
    {
        velocity.x -= 1;
    }
    if (Input.IsActionPressed("move_down"))
    {
        velocity.y += 1;
    }
    if (Input.IsActionPressed("move_up"))
    {
        velocity.y -= 1;
    }

    var animatedSprite = GetNode<AnimatedSprite>("AnimatedSprite");

    if (velocity.Length() > 0)
    {
        velocity = velocity.Normalized() * Speed;
        animatedSprite.Play();

    }
    else
    {
        animatedSprite.Stop();
    }

    Position += velocity * delta;
    Position = new Vector2(
        x: Mathf.Clamp(Position.x, 0, ScreenSize.x),
        y: Mathf.Clamp(Position.y, 0, ScreenSize.y)
        );

    if (velocity.x != 0)
    {
        animatedSprite.Animation = "walk";
        animatedSprite.FlipV = false;
        animatedSprite.FlipH = velocity.x < 0; //Here I'm doing a boolean 
    test
    }
    else if (velocity.y != 0)
    {
        animatedSprite.Animation = "up";
        animatedSprite.FlipV = velocity.y > 0; //Here I'm doing a boolean 
    test
    }
  }

public void On_Player_Body_Entered(PhysicsBody2D body)
{
    Hide(); //Player disappears after being hit.
    EmitSignal(nameof(Hit));
    //Must be deferred as we can't change physics properties on a physics 
    callback.
    GetNode<CollisionShape2D>("CollisionShape2D").SetDeferred("disabled", 
    true);
} 

//Reset the player when starting the game  
public void Start(Vector2 pos)
{
    Position = pos;
    Show();
    GetNode<CollisionShape2D>("CollisionShape2D").Disabled = false;
}
}
```

If you can help me, please.. I'd be very glad and thankful if you could! Thank you!

Comment: I assume your script is attached to the main scene isn't it? I can see that you also attached a script to your timer nodes. Are there any start functions in the timer scripts? Did the error occur on timeout or when you start your game?

Comment: As pointed out by @magenulcus there is a script attached to your timer.

Could you check in that script from which base your Timer inherits?

Because you can connect a script to a timer with a base like this:

public class StartTimer : Node

But this will throw an exception, if you try to cast it as an timer.

So make sure it looks like this:

public class StartTimer : Timer

Let me know if it helps, than I will formulate an answer in the thread

Comment: @magenulcus answering your questions: 1) Main.cs attached to the Main scene. 2) I think theses scripts in MobTimer, ScoreTimer and StartTimer was attached by the platform automatically, because it has signals in Main.cs, so all of them have Main.cs. 3) Error occurs inside New_Game() method and the window with game opens but closes immediatly. if I comment the GetNode<Timer> line, and start the game, I can see the player and move him around the scene. So, the error if thrown in GetNode<Timer> line.

Comment: @Bugfish I haven't created any script for StartTimer, the one you see in the screenshot, it seems was attached automatically by the platform Godot and it is all the Main.sc, which means I have Main Scene with Main.sc and all timers with Main.sc.

Comment: I just added all my scripts above in order to help you help me! Thank you so much!

Comment: It should not be the case, that a script is connected, when you connect a signal.
Just to be sure: If you select StartTimer, which script name is entered on the right hand in the properties?

If its really the main.cs it at least explains why the cast fails. Remove the script from the timers and it should be able to cast them properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your game crashes is because of the main.cs script that is attached to all timer nodes.

Since the main.cs script extends the `Node` object all your timers are becoming `Node` objects instead of `Timer` objects. And because Node objects do not have a `Start`() function your game crashes.

The simple solution to this is to detach the main script from all nodes but the main node.

As Bugfish pointed out, Godot must not attach a script to a node when you connect a signal. Especially not a script from another node. After you deleted your main script from the timers, I recommend to go through the process of signal connection again just to figure out what went wrong the first time.

Comment: It really solved my problem! Thank you so much all of you that helped me!